# Find items between dates with a varchar cols date in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have a datebase with a table calls "items".

Each item has a different cols one of them it calls "due_date" with this type of value "2016-05-19 13:25:22".

I want to find items between two days and I try to do this:

$from_date = 1462102645; //01 May

$to_date = 1464781045; //01 June

```
Items::all(array('conditions' => array('status = ? AND id = ? AND (STR_TO_DATE(due_date,'%Y-%m-%d2') BETWEEN ? AND ?)', 'done', $id, $from_date, $to_date)));
```

But it doesn't work, what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just change your $from_date and $to_date from UNIX timestamp to date()

e.g.:

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d", 1462102645);
```

Comment: `(STR_TO_DATE(due_date,'%Y-%m-%d2')` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I don't understand you rcomment  GunniH can you specify please what I have to do?

Comment: You're just writing `due_date`. If you look at the documentation I linked you can see that the first param should be an actual date. Also, the `%d2` should just be `%d`

Comment: Hi I correct the %d2 to %d but don't work yet....I write just due_date because i want fo filter just with this column date

Comment: Ok GunniH, I find the error it's about the quotes, I use ' instead of " and it works thanks =)

Comment: No problemo, remember to checkmark the post if it's solved :)

Comment: Hi again, it's not about the quote, because as I can seen it takes all items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112393/discussion-between-gunnih-and-met-el-idrissi).